# Solving Differential Equations Containing Trigonometric Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Can we find the first five solutions of the differential equation below using Leibnitz-Maclaurin's method?

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+(1+x^{2})y=\sin{x}$$

I tried solving it but got confused after finding the nth differential of $\sin{x} $

If not possible using Leibnitz-Maclaurin's method, how can I solve this question?

Comment: The $n$th derivative of $\sin x$ is $\sin(x + \frac{n\pi}{2})$. Does that give you enough information to solve the problem?

Comment: @DylanSp No, it doesn't. That's even  where my confusion begins because  getting the recurrence relation after fixing $x=0$ becomes problematic

Answer (score 2):

This first order ordinary differential equation can be solved using the method of [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First_order_equation). In this case, you obtain
\begin{equation}
 y(x) = e^{-x(1+x^2 /3)}\left(y(0) + \int_0^x e^{\xi(1+\xi^2 /3)}\sin\xi\,\text{d}\xi\right).
\end{equation}
If you are adamant on using the Leibniz-MacLaurin method, you can use the above to check your solution.

Comment: $x^2/3$ maybe ?

Comment: You're right. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Using the power series method you'd get something like this:

First let $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{a_kx^k} \Rightarrow f'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k+1}(k+1)x^k$. Next note that by inserting the powerseries for $f(x)$ that:

$$(1+x^2)f(x) = a_0 +a_1x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty {(a_k+a_{k-2})x^k}.$$

Now let $b_k$ be defined by:
$$b_k = \begin{cases}0 \quad \mbox{if $k$ is even,}\\
        \frac{(-1)^{\frac{k-1}{2}}}{k!} \quad \mbox{if k is odd.} \end{cases} $$

The $\sin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{b_kx^k} = x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty{b_kx^k}$ (its just a rewrite of the usual formula $\sin(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}}$).

Now inserting this knowledge into your differential equation we would get, that:

$$a_1+2a_2x +\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_{k+1}(k+1)x^k +a_0 +a_1x + \sum_{k=2}^\infty {(a_k+a_{k-2})x^k} - x-\sum_{k=2}^\infty{b_kx^k} =0$$

Collecting the coefficient to each power of $x$ and setting it equal to 0 we get the following recurrence equations:

\begin{align*}
 &a_1+a_0=0\\
 &2a_2 +a_1 -1 =0\\
 &(k+1)a_{k+1}+a_k+a_{k-1}-b_k=0, \quad  \mbox{ for $k\geq2$.}
\end{align*}

Now from the definition of $f$ we get that $a_0=y(0)$, so this number is known. Then we may successively solve for $a_k$.

Hope that was what you had in mind.